# Modify the DOM and use Lightning attributes (Lightning Components)

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-experience, lightning-apps

I'm trying to modify the DOM and access a lightning component attribute at the same method.

I tried using init handler but I can't access the DOM there.

I tried using render handler but I can't access the attribute there.

Is there a method I can access both ?
I need it to run in the beginning of the component lifecycle (like init or render)

```
init : function(component, event, helper){

    var pathItems = document.getElementsByClassName("slds-path__item");
    console.log('pathItems: ' + pathItems.length);
    for (var i=0; i<pathItems.length; i++){
        var item = pathItems[i];
        var status = item.getAttribute("data-value");
        var commission = component.get("v.commission");

        //first set incomplete
        $A.util.addClass(item, 'slds-is-incomplete');
        console.log('status: ' + commission.Status__c);
        if (status == commission.Status__c){
            $A.util.removeClass(item, 'slds-is-incomplete');
            $A.util.addClass(item, 'slds-is-active');
            $A.util.addClass(item, 'slds-is-current');

            if (status == 'Pending Final Approval'){
                $A.util.removeClass(pathItems[i-1], 'slds-is-incomplete');
                $A.util.addClass(pathItems[i-1], 'slds-is-complete');
            }
            else if (status == 'Approved For Payment'){
                $A.util.removeClass(pathItems[i-1], 'slds-is-incomplete');
                $A.util.addClass(pathItems[i-1], 'slds-is-complete');
                $A.util.removeClass(pathItems[i-2], 'slds-is-incomplete');
                $A.util.addClass(pathItems[i-2], 'slds-is-complete');
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the DOM until after it has been rendered initially. I actually implemented path using only expressions, no direct class manipulation required. That said, for DOM manipulation, use [`afterRender`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_renderers.htm) instead. There's actually several examples of path components already built you can look at, such as [`strike_path`](http://www.lightningstrike.io/#!/strikePath). Also note that `render` passes in all the elements that will be created, so you can manipulate the classes of those elements before being added to the DOM, which would give better performance.

Comment: Thanks for the response, when I use afterRender, I get this error: "Failed to initialize a component [Cannot read property 'g' of undefined]". I don't know how to solve this.

Comment: @osos9 We'd need to see the afterRender method you wrote to figure out what's up, but again, I'd suggest not using a custom renderer, it's simply not necessary.

Comment: I paste the method in the question (called init). What do you mean by "custom renderer" ?

Comment: @osos9 See the link for `afterRender` in this answer. It talks about custom renderers.